# JRuby rspec exception after installing simplecov

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, jruby, code-coverage

Trying to add simplecov to my Rails app (Jruby 1.6.4, Ruby 1.9.2, Windows). I added 'simplecov' to the Gemfile, bundle install, and the following to the top of my spec_helper:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start 'rails'
```

When run I get the following exception:

```
$ bundle exec rspec --debug spec

No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-base-0.10.4-java/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:214 warning: tracing (e.g. set_trace_func) will not capture all events without --debug flag
c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/simplecov-0.5.4/lib/simplecov.rb:33 warning: tracing (e.g. set_trace_func) will not capture all events without --debug flag
LoadError: load error: rails/railtie -- java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: null
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1047
           (root) at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:1
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1047
           (root) at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:1
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1047
           (root) at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/plugin.rb:4
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1047
           (root) at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:10
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1047
           (root) at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails.rb:1
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1047
           (root) at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:5
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1047
           (root) at c:/dev/railsProjects/txprepaid/config/application.rb:2
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1047
           (root) at c:/dev/railsProjects/txprepaid/config/environment.rb:13
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1047
           (root) at c:/dev/railsProjects/txprepaid/spec/spec_helper.rb:1
             load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1073
  load_spec_files at c:/dev/railsProjects/txprepaid/spec/controllers/dictionary_controller_spec.rb:459
          collect at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2344
  load_spec_files at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459
              run at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18
   run_in_process at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80
              run at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:66
          autorun at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10
ArgumentError: same file: c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/simplecov-html-0.5.3/lib/../assets/app.js and C:/dev/railsProjects/txprepaid/coverage/assets/0.5.3/app.js
   fu_each_src_dest at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:1417
  fu_each_src_dest0 at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:1432
   fu_each_src_dest at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:1416
               cp_r at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb:432
             format at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/simplecov-html-0.5.3/lib/simplecov-html.rb:15
               each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1603
             format at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/simplecov-html-0.5.3/lib/simplecov-html.rb:14
            format! at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/simplecov-0.5.4/lib/simplecov/result.rb:90
            at_exit at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/simplecov-0.5.4/lib/simplecov/configuration.rb:133
               call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:262
             (root) at c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/simplecov-0.5.4/lib/simplecov/defaults.rb:47
```

Comment: don't think you need the require 'rubygems' ; I know my spec_helper.rb does not have it. I use spork though so my first line is require 'spork'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would look like not all the support for coverage support is available in JRuby as can be seen in the links below, this is probably affecting simplecov as it relies on the in built coverage functionality that is expected in Ruby 1.9.

https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/issues/86

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6106

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5935

Comment: I think you're right, ran project in mri 1.9.2 and simplecov works without a problem, ugh.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jruby in 1.9 mode. You can pass --1.9, but I typically put

```
JRUBY_OPTS="--1.9"
```

in my .bashrc. Not sure how to set env variables in Windows though.